# Is there a `liftIO` equivalence for conduits?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm writing a conduit that is growing quite big, with nested monad transforms. It's a tedious work to `lift` each and every `yield` or `await` call into the base `conduitM`. Not to mention every time I add or withdraw a layer of transformation, I need to change the number of `lift`'s at every possible location.

I was looking for a similar function as `liftIO`, but instead of lifting an IO operation it should lift `yield` or `await` into an arbitrarily transformed monad based on `ConduitM`, but I can't seem to find one. Is there a way to achieve something like this?

---

**Edit:** in response to @BradleyHardy's answer, here I provide a concrete example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

import Control.Monad                    as MON 
import Control.Monad.IO.Class           as MIO 
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class        as MTC 
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe        as MTM 
import Data.Conduit                     as CDT 
import System.IO                        as IO

stdinS :: Source IO String
stdinS = void . runMaybeT . forever $ do
    (liftIO isEOF) >>= \case
        True  -> mzero
        False -> (lift . yield) =<< (liftIO getLine)

myK :: Sink String IO ()
myK = void . runMaybeT . forever . runMaybeT $ do
    a <- maybe (lift mzero) return =<< (lift . lift $ await)
    b <- if a == "listen"
      then maybe (lift mzero) return =<< (lift . lift $ await)
      else mzero
    liftIO . putStrLn $ "I heard: " ++ b

main :: IO ()
main = do
    stdinS $$ myK
```

How would you change `myK` to put `ConduitM` on top of the stack? Admittedly in this particular example using `MaybeT` is over-complication, but in my actual (much larger) conduit `MaybeT` structure is much cleaner than e.g. recursions.

Comment: `ConduitM m` is an instance of `MonadIO` if `MonadIO m`, so so you have `liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> ConduitM i o m a`. `ConduitM` also has instances for all of the MTL classes (MonadReader/Writer, etc) since `ConduitM` is a monad transformer, so you dont have to write `lift ask :: ConduitM i o (Reader r) r` (for example), you can just do `ask :: ConduitM i o (Reader r) r`.

Comment: @user2407038: Thanks for the answer, but I wasn't quite sure what should I do with `yield`s and `await`s.

Comment: What you should do with yield and await doesn't seem to have anything to do with lifting IO actions in conduits? Perhaps you should include a concrete example of what you wish to achieve. If you mean something like a `MonadConduit` (analogous to MonadReader/Writer/etc) class, this doesn't exist, however `pipes` solves this problem and essentially does the same thing as `Conduit` (see [Control.Proxy.Trans](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-3.2.0/docs/Control-Proxy-Trans.html))

Comment: @user2407038: I added a concrete example showing what I have in mind.

Comment: The reason that you can't place ConduitM at the top of the stack is that doesn't have a `MonadPlus` instance. I would expect something like `MonadPlus m => MonadPlus (ConduitM i o m)` to exist, but that doesn't seem to be the case - I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better way is to use the included [`Data.Conduit.Lift`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.5.1/docs/Data-Conduit-Lift.html) module. It is as simple as replacing all your `runMaybeT`, `runStateT`, etc. into `runMaybeC` and `runStateC`. And voila, the `ConduitM` is pushed to the top of the transformer stack.

Answer (score 4):

`ConduitM` is *itself* a monad transformer, and, looking at the [Haddock page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.5.1/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t:ConduitM) for it, we see that it defines instances for `MonadState`, `MonadReader`, etc. This should suggest that in fact the pattern intended is to have `ConduitM` at the top of the transformer stack, in which case you don't need to lift any operations into it.

In fact, it even defines an instance for [MonadBase](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-base-0.4.4/docs/Control-Monad-Base.html#t:MonadBase), the class which lets you lift operations from the monad which sits at the very base of the stack (using the `liftBase` function), so that if reordering your stack means it's hard to access the *new* thing at the bottom, `MonadBase` solves this for you. If you have `IO` at the bottom anyway though, this probably isn't very helpful.

**I would suggest that you try to reorder your transformer stack to put `ConduitM` on top if possible.**

**EDIT:** Another option would be to create your own class, `MonadConduit`, which defines generalised `yield` and `await` functions, and add instances for `ConduitM` and every other transformer you use on top of it. I think that this is less elegant than reordering your stack if possible though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I wasn't able to see a way to put `ConduitM` at the top in my application. The conduit I'm writing awaits and yields unpredictable number of items in each iteration, and the `await`s and `yield`s are deeply buried at complicatedly nested `if`s and `case`s.

Comment: As for `liftBase`, I notice that `conduitM` is *not* a base itself: `MonadBase base m => MonadBase base (ConduitM i o m)`. This means that the base would be `IO` -- and *not* `conduitM ...` -- if my `conduitM` is based on `IO`-monad.

Comment: @trVoldemort What layers do you have in your stack? Are there things like `ListT` or `LogicT` that might have different behaviour if swapped around? If so, I think you might do well to rethink your program's structure.

As for the `MonadBase` thing, yes, you're right but that's not what I meant. I'll edit my answer for clarity.